# flutter_flavorizr cannot create separate app with different app_id/bundle_id for creating variant in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, variant

I am trying to use:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr

to create different variants in flutter. Example: different localized apps.

Check out the screenshots here:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- Runner.xcworkspace - there is only one (shouldnt it be different mandarin/arabic)
- I noticed appicon assets there is seperate files
- I'ved pubspec.yaml according to flutter_flavorizr specifying the different flavors appid/bundleid
- in the screenshot, you could see an empty bundle id in xcode

flutter_flavorizr cannot create different apps with different app_id / bundle_id ?

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub run flutter_flavorizr`? to process config?

Comment: yes. i followed this all the way https://medium.com/@angeloavv/easily-build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-flutter-flavorizr-d48cbf956e4, what is lacking in the writeup is whether it creates a separate project for the various platform. as far as I have tried, it appears not